# Energy sharing in series

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits

The internet tells me that:

> The voltage (from the power supply) is shared across each bulb in a series circuit because the energy carried by the electrons is used as they pass through the components.

However, I believe this is likely to be incorrect since electrons do not carry energy per se. At least I don't think they do? They carry charge and the movement of this charge transfers energy around the circuit through generation of the electric field.

So how does one explain why voltage is shared in a circuit with components in series?

I would rather receive an intuitive explanation as opposed to 'current is fixed' so just use $V = IR$.

Comment: *So how does one explain why voltage is shared in a circuit with components in series?* - to be clear, you're not accepting Kirchoff's voltage law  (KVL) as an explanation. Or are you asking to explain KVL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider it in this way, voltage in a way is work done in moving a charge. When we have a series connection of 'n' resistors, we would need to perform work to push the charge across all of them and the total work would be a summation of the work done to move it across one of those 'n' resistors. The total work refers to the voltage drop across the entire series of resistors which is getting split for overcoming each resistor

Answer (score 0):

I am reminded of the revised  A-level syllabus that was introduced in parts of the UK after we got  PM who  replaced the professional teachers    by a committees  of businessmen: "In a series circuit the bulbs gradually get dimmer as electrons are used up as they pass through successive lamps ---  but remember that the full voltage of the battery is across each bulb in a series circuit."

The quote "The voltage (from the power supply) is shared across each bulb in a series circuit because the energy carried by the electrons is used as they pass through the components."  seems to be similarly nonsensical.

PS: I can't find the text of the revised online, but it in was a phyiscs teacher magazine in the 1980's .